# Printing in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a transaction i want to print an error message. My problem is that even if there is no error I still print one on the screen. How do i fix it?
The transaction, with the print statement in it:

```
begin tran update_products_and_machine
IF  EXISTS (

                select*  
                from TblMachine  
                where tblMachine.machineNumber = @machineNum and tblMachine.isworking='true')
and  EXISTS  (
                select TblProduct.productNumber 
                from TblProduct 
                where TblProduct.productNumber = @ProductNum)

and not exists (select TblProduces.machineNumber, TblProduces.productNumber from TblProduces where TblProduces.productNumber=@productNum
and TblProduces.machineNumber=@machineNum)

 begin
insert into TblProduces(productNumber, machineNumber) values (@productNum,@machineNum)
end
if @@ERROR <>0 begin
rollback tran
end
commit tran update_products_and_machine
on_error: Print 'ERROR';
```

Comment: you need to move the print to under the "if @@ERROR <>0 begin" line

Comment: You should just be able to move `Print 'ERROR'` after `rollback tran`.

Comment: Jeff/Jimbo, when I do as you suggested, I don't get the error message at all, even if there is an error

Answer (score 0):

```
begin tran update_products_and_machine
IF  EXISTS (

            select*  
            from TblMachine  
            where tblMachine.machineNumber = @machineNum and 
tblMachine.isworking='true')
and  EXISTS  (
            select TblProduct.productNumber 
            from TblProduct 
            where TblProduct.productNumber = @ProductNum)

and not exists (select TblProduces.machineNumber, TblProduces.productNumber from  
TblProduces where TblProduces.productNumber=@productNum
and TblProduces.machineNumber=@machineNum)

begin
insert into TblProduces(productNumber, machineNumber) values (@productNum,@machineNum)
end
if @@ERROR <>0 begin
rollback tran
Print 'ERROR';
end
commit tran update_products_and_machine
```

Comment: Hey Dustin, this solution doens't print ERROR when there is one, all it does is print: "Command(s) completed successfully"

Comment: Are you parsing the query or executing it?

Comment: What version of sql are you using? I ran the query and got the expected results (Sql 2008)

Comment: Try running this: if @@ERROR <>0 
begin
Print 'ERROR';
Print @@ERROR
end
Print 'NO ERROR'    Add a line at the beginning of the statements that will cause an error. It should work

Comment: This should work...just copy and paste:                     causeError
if @@ERROR <>0 
begin
Print 'ERROR';
end

Comment: After I checked some thing, I noticed that i never enter the "if" statement, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle Copy and Paste into SQL Server (it will only work there, as SQL Fiddle doesn't allow explicit commits).](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f1cee9/1)

If you're trying to `PRINT` "Error" when the transaction fails on the `INSERT`, the second `IF` needs to be within the first `IF`'s block because the first `IF` is whether something exists, not whether an error exists.  Do we get an error if we don't find anything in tables?  No.  Whereas here:

```
BEGIN TRAN update_products_and_machine
IF  EXISTS (

            select*  
            from TblMachine  
            where tblMachine.machineNumber = @machineNum and 
tblMachine.isworking='true')
and  EXISTS  (
            select TblProduct.productNumber 
            from TblProduct 
            where TblProduct.productNumber = @ProductNum)

and not exists (select TblProduces.machineNumber, TblProduces.productNumber from  
TblProduces where TblProduces.productNumber=@productNum
and TblProduces.machineNumber=@machineNum)

BEGIN
insert into TblProduces(productNumber, machineNumber) values (@productNum,@machineNum)
     IF @@ERROR <> 0 
     BEGIN
          rollback tran
          Print 'ERROR';
     END
END

COMMIT TRAN update_products_and_machine
```

This will error if the `INSERT` fails.  If the two items in the first block aren't found (they are seeking `IF EXISTS` and `IF NOT EXISTS`), how is that an error - it is a completed transaction that didn't find anything?